# give it to him to examine

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-usage

> Give the fabric to John to examine.

Let's say I'm telling somebody called Joe to give another person (John) a piece of fabric to examine it. Can I say the sentence above instead of,

> Give the fabric to John for John to examine it.

and instead of the sentence below if it is Joe who I'm asking to examine the fabric?

> Give the fabric to John for you to examine it.

And if it's not clear who I want to examine the fabric, I should say the second or the third sentence, is my understanding correct? Also, should I say "it" after "examine"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can say

> Give the fabric to John to examine.

It is perfectly normal English, and means what you suggested.

Also,

> Give the fabric to John for you to examine it.

Is also fine. You could omit the 'it', and at first I thought that was more natural; but I don't think so now. I think that, because the instruction is a bit unexpected, I would probably expect the 'it', for clarity. But, for example:

> Ask John to bring the fabric for you to examine.

would be fine without the 'it'.

Comment: Not sure what you think this means: "Give the fabric to John for you to examine it."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I said it was a bit unexpected. I would assume that John will then be holding it up for you.